# Retrieve WordPress' the_content() with jQuery

Tags: theme-development, loop, ajax

I'm trying to load some additional images when the user clicks a button. At the moment, I have the following function:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $( ".gallery-pop-up-container" )
    .load( "wp-content/themes/fashion_detail/includes/single/gallery-pop-up.php");
});
```

and I'm trying to load:

```
<div class="gallery-page">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
```

However, I get a PHP error, because it's not sure what the function is:

```
 Fatal error: Call to undefined function the_content()
```

What would be the best way for me to load `the_content()`?

Comment: Before use the_content or any other WordPress function you need to load WordPress. Use [Ajax API](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins). Also have a look [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ajax?sort=votes&pageSize=50)

Answer (score 1):

As @G.M pointed out, you need to levy the awesome [AJAX API](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins). In the example below, we fire a request to the AJAX handler, along with the parameter `action=gallery_popup`.

```
$( "a" ).click(
    function () {
        $( ".gallery-pop-up-container" ).load( "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=gallery_popup" );
    }
);
```

In response to this request, WordPress will trigger an action of the same name, prefixed with `wp_ajax_...` (or `wp_ajax_nopriv_...` if the current user is not logged in).

So all we do now is hook onto said action and output the template part:

```
function wpse_137607_gallery_popup() {
    get_template_part( 'includes/single/gallery-pop-up.php' );
    exit;
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_gallery_popup', 'wpse_137607_gallery_popup' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_gallery_popup',        'wpse_137607_gallery_popup' );
```

And you're done!